# Does this implementation of CompletableFuture actually bring any benefit?

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, completable-future

I'm learning java completable future.

I decided to rewrite this chunk of code to practice:

```
Product product = productRepository.findByUuid(UUID.fromString(productUuid)).orElse(null);
if (product == null)
    // return some error

List<ProductCollection> collections = collectionRepository.findAll();
List<ProductCategory> categories = categorieyRepository.findAll();

return ResponseEntity.ok(new AdminProductDetailDTO(
    product,
    collections,
    categories
));
```

And came up with this:

```
if (!productRepository.existsByUuid(UUID.fromString(productUuid)))
    // return some error

CompletableFuture<Product> products = productService.findByUuid(productUuid);
CompletableFuture<List<ProductCollection>> collections = collectionService.findAll();
CompletableFuture<List<ProductCategory>> categories = categoryService.findAll();

return ResponseEntity.ok(new AdminProductDetailDTO(
    products.get(),
    collections.get(),
    categories.get()
));

// Collection service
@Async
public CompletableFuture<List<ProductCollection>> findAll() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(collectionRepository::findAll);
}

// Category service
@Async
public CompletableFuture<List<ProductCategory>> findAll() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(categoryRepository::findAll);
}
```

When I test my endpoint on postman, I can see that the execution time is very similar on both versions. Is this the correct way of implementing this?

Comment: How many `ProductCategory`, `ProductCollection` items are you expecting and from what system (remote db, etc.)? If the items are very few, then the time might in fact be similar (unnoticable difference).

Comment: You have three actions that may run in parallel, but now there’s the fourth, `existsByUuid` , that is executed first. It’s very likely that this operation is in the order of magnitude of `findByUuid`. So you’re replacing `A + B + C` with `A + max(A, B, C) + Overhead`. As Hasan said, you might not gain anything if the number of items is small, but there might also be other limiting factors, e.g. all operations might go over the same network, etc.